# Is there a size limit on data stored in the flash[] object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the following scenario:

1. A user fills in a form and POSTs it.
2. The POST handler does some calculation that returns a large amount of data.
3. The handler redirects to a GET path that will display that data.

I want to use `flash` to transfer that data.  That is, the POST handler will look something like:

```
flash[:big_data] = result
redirect_to show_big_result_path
```

Is this safe?  Or is there a limit on the data `flash` is capable of handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in the session, just like using `session[:big_data]`.

Session has a limit of 4K, however, you can change your session store in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Here is an example of an alternate session store https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store

Comment: Thank you.  Is there an alternative with a much larger limit?  Eg, some way to use `Rails.cache` with file store in a "valid only as long as this redirect" way?

Comment: RE: "valid only as long as this redirect". Is there a reason you don't want to handle deleting this stored value when landing on the redirect action? For example, for small data using the session, you can always do something like `session.data.delete :text`

As far as alternate stores are concerned, I would look into Memcache.

Comment: To answer your earlier question, Rails.cache would work the same as any other solution that you have to handle the garbage collection. A database or memcache store would work the same way. I don't know of a solution that Rails has pre-built garbage collection for.

I'm sure you're aware, but just to mention it, you can store these records against the session id.

Comment: I'm currently using `Rails.cache` manually as you suggested... I'm just curious if there is a preferred way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163918/discussion-between-rantingsonrails-and-jonah).